# SharePoint 2013 blog site - Blog preview with read more link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How do I setup the home page of a blog site so it previews a certain amount of the content and adds a read more link when the limit is reached? I know this could be done in 2010 with XSLT, but this is no longer a viable solution in 2013